# www.example.com redirects to https://www.www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all traffic to https://www.example.com. I have .htaccess rules set as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Both DNS A records (www and non-www) are pointing to the same IP. That results with www.example.com redirecting to https://www.www.example.com What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of this line in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Should fix that issue. Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but after that change I got too many redirections error message.

Comment: Hey @Robert - that is likely caused by this line `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]`, change that to `RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [OR]`

Comment: That's not fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed it to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

and it works fine. Thanks for help Joe.